# Show that the distribution of $X$ is like this:

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, variance

Suppose $E(X)=\mu$ and $V(X)=\sigma^2$. Show that if $P(|X-\mu|\geq k)=\frac{\sigma^2}{k^2}$ then we have:
$$P(X=\mu)=\frac{k^2-\sigma^2}{k^2}, P(X=\mu-k)=P(X=\mu+k)=\frac{\sigma^2}{2k^2}$$

I know how to prove the inverse of this theorem. But I have no idea how to prove this side. Would you help me? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Shouldn't $P(X=\mu+k)$ be $\sigma^2/2k^2$?

Comment: @Golden_Ratio Is there a flaw in my reasoning? Because $\sigma^2/2k^2$ won't  coalesce with it.

Comment: The masses must sum to one though

Comment: Btw, I meant $\sigma^2/(2k^2)$

Comment: @Golden_Ratio You're right. Sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume $0<\sigma\leq k$. First, we show  $\text{supp}\{X\}\subseteq\{\mu,\mu+k,\mu-k\}.$

Lemma: Suppose $Z\geq 0,a>0$ and  $P(Z\geq a)=E[Z]/a.$ Then $\text{supp}\{Z\}\subseteq\{0,a\}$

Proof: Note ${\bf 1}_{Z\geq a}\leq Z/a$ for $Z\geq 0$ with equality only holding at $Z=0,a.$ Hence  $P(Z\geq a)=E[{\bf 1}_{Z\geq a}]= E[Z/a]$ only if $Z=0$ or $Z=a$ a.s.$\square$

Now we are given $\frac{1}{k^2/\sigma^2}=P(|X-\mu|\geq k)=P\left(\frac{(X-\mu)^2}{\sigma^2}\geq \frac{k^2}{\sigma^2}\right),$ so the claimed three-point support follows immediately from our lemma.

Now we simply need to find the mass on each point. Note
$$P(X=\mu)=P(|X-\mu|< k)=1-P(|X-\mu|\geq k)=1-\frac{\sigma^2}{k^2}.$$

Noting the three masses sum to unity, and $\mu+k$ and $\mu-k$ are equidistant from mean $\mu$, the other masses follow:

$$P(X=\mu+k)=P(X=\mu-k)=\frac{\sigma^2}{2k^2}.$$

Comment: How do we prove that if two points are equidistant from mean, their masses are equal?

Comment: @James, you have two equations ($X$ has mean $\mu$ and masses sum to one) and two unknowns (mass on $\mu \pm k$)

Comment: I still don't get it. Why should they have to be equal?

Comment: Write an equation for the mean of $X$ to be $\mu.$ Write an equation for the probabilities summing to 1. Solve for the masses not on $\mu$ and show they are equal.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Now in the following I will assume that $X$ is discrete and that it has as support all the integers $\mathbb{Z}$. Note that from $\mathbb{P}(\lvert X-\mu\rvert\geq k) = \frac{\sigma^2}{k^ 2}$,

\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\lvert X-\mu\rvert < k) = 1 - \frac{\sigma^2}{k^ 2} = \frac{k^ 2 - \sigma^2}{k^ 2}.
\end{align}
Which implies,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X = \mu) = \mathbb{P}(\lvert X-\mu\rvert = 0) = \mathbb{P}(\lvert X-\mu\rvert < 1) = 1 - \sigma^2.
\end{align}

Note,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(\lvert X-\mu\rvert \geq k) &= \mathbb{P}(\{X-\mu\geq k\}\cup\{X-\mu \leq -k\}), \\[1em]
&\stackrel{m.e.}{=} \mathbb{P}( X \geq \mu + k) + \mathbb{P}( X \leq \mu - k) = \frac{\sigma^2}{k^2}.
\end{align}
So that,
\begin{align}
\frac{\sigma^2}{k^2} - \frac{\sigma^2}{(k+1)^2} &= \mathbb{P}( X \geq \mu + k) + \mathbb{P}( X \leq \mu - k) - \left(\mathbb{P}( X \geq \mu + k + 1) + \mathbb{P}( X \leq \mu - k-1)\right), \\[1em]
&= \mathbb{P}( X \geq \mu + k) - \mathbb{P}( X \geq \mu + k + 1) + \mathbb{P}( X \leq \mu - k) - \mathbb{P}( X \leq \mu - k-1), \\[1em]
&= \mathbb{P}(X=\mu+k) + \mathbb{P}(X=\mu - k).
\end{align}

Assuming that the support equals the integers, we must have,
\begin{align}
\mathbb{P}(X=\mu)+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \mathbb{P}(X=\mu+k) + \mathbb{P}(X=\mu - k) &= 1-\sigma^2 + \sigma^2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} \left(\frac{1}{k^2} - \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right) \\[1em]
&= 1-\sigma^2 +\sigma^2\left(\left(1 - \frac{1}{4}\right) + \left(\frac{1}{4} - \frac{1}{9}\right) + \dots\right) \\[1em]
&= 1.
\end{align}

Nevertheless, since,

$$\mathbb{P}(X=\mu+k) + \mathbb{P}(X=\mu - k) = \sigma^2\left(\frac{1}{k^2} - \frac{1}{(k+1)^2}\right).$$

These probabilities cannot equal each other and be equal to $\frac{\sigma^2}{2k}$ as you suggest.